# How could skin be made as hard as diamond or graphene, whilst retaining it's current flexibility?

Tags: material-science, graphene, diamond

I want to understand what exactly the difference is between skin, on a molecular, atomic and quantum level, and materials like diamond and graphene. Then I wish to understand the changes that would have to be performed to alter the structure and composition of skin to exhibit the qualities of diamond and graphene (hardness), whilst retaining its current flexibility. Is it a matter of structure, bonding, and/or composition? Also, is there another way to improve the durability of the skin?

Comment: Are you asking about scratch hardness, indentation hardness, or rebound hardness. Similarly, for skin are you asking about malleability, ductility, or some other physical quantity that captures the idea of “flexibility”. It would help to be more specific about what properties you want to combine.

Comment: What do you mean by "skin"? human skin? because the properties change with age... Because the term "skin" is used in many places - on an aircraft wing it is an aluminum panel...  Note, some of us are also busy - you are not the only one.

Comment: Indeed, the question is far too broad, covering materials science, biology, leather work. Perhaps cow or crocodile skin...

Comment: You know that skin is a [hugely complex biological organ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_skin), not just a sheet of material, right?

Comment: Hi Dale. Durability encompasses scratch resistance, piercing resistance, burn resisting, corrosion resistance, and indentation resistance. Flexibility is about the range of movement possible with the covering; so, will it restrict movement if hardened, and will it retain the ability to stretch?

Comment: Hi Mike. I mean human skin. Yes I know others are busy.

Comment: Hi Stephane. Yes I do know that. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

for a material like diamond or graphene to be resistant to being deformed, the bonds which connect its atoms together into a 3-dimensional network must be fixed in position relative to the 3-D lattice- so that when you attempt to bend a piece of that material, the interatomic bonds strongly oppose having their *bond angles* changed.

For a material like human skin to be flexible requires the materials that compose it to be readily elastic and capable of being folded and unfolded many times without tearing. This requires that skin *not* be composed of a solid 3-D network of atoms with directionally "stiff" interatomic bonding, but instead be made up of either a fibrous or porous/cellular network of molecules whose bond angles can be bent and where the individual molecules can slip past one another at least slightly.

Comment: Okay. So how would skin need to be modified to retain flexibility whilst being more resistant to damage (piercing, cutting, tearing, burning, corrosion etc.)?

Comment: You can have one or the other but not both in the same material. The things you need to be resistant to piercing and cutting will prevent flexibility, and vice versa.

Comment: What about rubber, or spider silk? They seem more resistant than skin but retain flexibility. What makes durability/hardness and flexibility incompatible, and how could this problem be resolved? I came across this:  https://www.google.com/amp/s/futurism.com/researchers-create-soft-flexible-material-thats-5-times-stronger-than-steel/amp

Comment: Are you a college student? Have you taken a second-year course in mechanics of materials? There are a few standard reference works in this field which would be helpful.

Comment: Hi niels. I am not a student, and when I was it was not in physics. Any materials you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at the materials science texts by Van Vlack and Shackelford, they will introduce you to this field and acquaint you with the basics.

Comment: Thanks alot niels. Have a great day.